# Admob screen location on iOS

Tags: smartface.io

I build iOS app using Smartface. I add Admob on my app, Admob shows center of the screen. When I add Admob into a container, Admob does not show. When I change Admob.top value does not happen anything.

How can I change the admob location on the screen in iOS?

Comment: Anybody see this question?

Answer (score 0):

You can try the codeLines below in the construction of AdMob;

```
 var admobLeft = (Device.screenWidth - 320) / 2;
    admob = new SMF.UI.AdMob({
            top : "92.5%",
            left : admobLeft,
            animated : true
        });
```